# Изменение высоты toolbar

Tags: android

Как программно менять высоту toolbar, и есть ли возможность расположения иконок не с правого края , а по центру?

Comment: Добавте в вопрос код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Смена высоты программно**

```
Toolbar.LayoutParams params = (Toolbar.LayoutParams)mToolbar.getLayoutParams();
params.height = 42; //высота
mToolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
```

---

А про иконки с правого края по центру просто одной строчкой не получится.
Создайте `layout` в `toolbar` и разместите иконки равноудаленно и переопределите их на нажатие.